# VBA Code for Excel VBA Lookup based on multiple inputs(partial)

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel Sheet format is similar to this

```
Name code1  Name Code2  Name       Number    Input1   Input2   
AB           XY        GSABPEXY1    110      BA       BC
BC           BA        GSBCPEBA1    120
CD           CA        GSCDPECA1    13
DC           DA        GSDCPEDA3    140
BC           BA        GSBCPEBA3    15
```

Question:

1. I want to obtain the values in the Name column by matching the inputs as in Input1 AND Input2.
2. I need these matched values to be pasted in another sheet's predefined specific row and columns cells
3. Using excel function countifs i am counting the number of rows having same  repeating values in the Column A (name code1) and B (name code2) e.g. in above BC and BA which gives a count of 2.
4. I would like to use this value (mentioned in #3) for the loop iteration

I got this code which looks very close but it lacks two things ABC is predefined in INSTR function and it doesn't have the AND operator - i do not know how to do it. I am very new to VBA so please pardon me if I am missing something simple and/or providing less info.

Code:

```
Sub Hostname()
    Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
    K = 1
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    w1.Activate
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, "ABC") > 0 Then
            r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a third column with value `Input1&Input2` and do a lookup on that? You wouldn't need any vba at all to do a lookup that way.

Comment: The thing is the Input1 and Input2 are not enough to do vlookup for getting all the values from the column C as in the sheet above. If you notice if I use only the input BA and BC and use Vlookup I will only get the first GSBCPEBA1 and not the second match GSBCPEBA3. I am not sure if vlookup can do loop like things.

Comment: No, VLookup is not good for doing iterations. I have put some sample code down as an answer based on my understanding of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I see what you want to do. How about this?

```
Sub Hostname()

    Dim codeName1 As String
    Dim codeName2 as string
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim targetRange as Range

    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyTargetSheetName").Range("AddressOfFirstCellForDataInput")
    codeName1 = "BC"
    codeName2 = "BA"

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
        with r
            If .Value2 = codeName1 And .Offset(0, 1).Value2 = codeName2 Then
                targetRange.Offset(count, 0).value = .Offset(0, 2).Value2
                count = count + 1
            ElseIf Len(Trim(.Value2)) = 0 Then
                Exit For
            end if
        End With
    Next

    Call msgbox("Found " & count & "cells matching Name code 1: " & codeName1 & " Name code 2: " & codeName2)
End Sub
```

This will count the number of cells which match Name Code 1 and Name Code 2. Cand you adapt this to do what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to run this code but it's not giving any output. I changed For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A") -> For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("C:C") and ElseIf Len(Trim(.Value2) = 0 Then -> to ElseIf Len(Trim(.Value2)) = 0 Then

Comment: This change `ElseIf Len(Trim(.Value2) = 0 Then` -> to `ElseIf Len(Trim(.Value2)) = 0 Then` is good, I forgot a parentheses there. The other change is wrong for what you want I think. I'll modify the code now so it will give you an output. Try it again and let me know. What exactly do you want to output though?

Comment: The code I am looking for match whether the values taken from Input1 AND Input2 are present(or contained partially) in any the cells of column C and if they are present there then copy the value of those cells into another sheet say sheet2's predecided cells. The checking of match should be iterative until the value which can be taken from another column (say F and cell F1). Hope this information may help.

Comment: OK, I'll modify it again to do that.

Comment: How about now? You will need to modify the name of the target worksheet and the address of the target cell obviously.

Comment: I tried this code for the same worksheet i provided above using the code I expect the values GSBCPEBA1 and GSBCPEBA3 from column named as Name to be copied and pasted to another sheet (Targetsheet). But when I run your code 1. I get message box (which is not my requirement) 2. it is not matching also anything says 0cells found matching Name code 1:BA codeName1:BC.

Comment: I do not know where to repsond except the comments.i cannot chat not as i do not have enough reputations(only 1).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you anymore than this. This code will do what you are looking for, but you have to adapt it to your situation. Unfortunately I do not have your spreadsheet here to see what exactly you want to do.
If the code is not finding the Code Name 1 and Code Name 2, then that means the values in the cells must be different from the ones I hard coded in there. You can see those, right? Maybe you've got extra spaces?
If you don't need the messagebox, just delete or comment out that line from the code.